# Qt - Why I can't cast my custom QGraphicsItem to QObject?

Tags: c++, qt

I've been struggling with Qt slots and signals for a while now. This connect is generating this error :

> moc_nodeitem.cpp:68: error: invalid static_cast from type 'QObject*' to type 'NodeItem*'
>            NodeItem *_t = static_cast(_o);
>                                                     ^

```
void GraphScene::addArcDestination(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
    NodeItem *item = dynamic_cast<NodeItem *>(itemAt(event->scenePos(), QTransform()));
    if (item){
        currentArc->setDestination(item);
        connect(item, &NodeItem::destroyed, currentArc, &ArcItem::deleteThis);
        connect(currentArc->getSource(), &NodeItem::destroyed, currentArc, &ArcItem::deleteThis);
        update();
    }else {
        removeItem(currentArc);
        update();
    }
}
```

So I added a static cast `connect(static_cast<QObject*>(item), &NodeItem::destroyed, currentArc, &ArcItem::deleteThis);` in my file and it basically says that my custom class doesn't inherit from QObject. However this is the NodeItem implementation and it inherits from QObject indirectly through QGraphicsItem.

This is the NodeItem implementation :

```
class NodeItem : public QGraphicsItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    NodeItem(QPointF);

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option , QWidget *widget) override;
    QRectF boundingRect() const override;
    QPainterPath shape() const override;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Node> node;

signals:
    void destroyed();
};
```

Please let me know if you need any more information or code.

Comment: QGraphicsItem doesn't derive from QObject. Also why a static_cast? It would be a dynamic_cast or preferably qobject_cast

Comment: I just used static_cast to see whether QGraphicsItem derives from QObject. I was convinced that it inherits from QObject. How to use signals then if it doesn't derive QObject ?

Comment: I added QObject as Base class and it worked. I feel silly now. Thanks for the help mate.